# Possibility of contructing a valid transaction without knowning private key

Tags: transactions, ecdsa, validation

From [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm) you get that in step 2 of ECDSA sign process, you use 
*z*, the *Ln*  leftmost bits of *e* = HASH(message/transaction) in both the process of generating and verifing the signature.

I understand that in bitcoin transactions signature and verification you do almost the same algorithm.

So...

You know that adress **A** has a transaction *x* to it that values in 1 BTC not spent.

You know also a transaction *y1* from **A** with a certain signature and a certain value *z1*, as the algorithm in the link says.

Could you create a transaction *y2* so that it sends the 1 BTC from **A** to adress **B** by creating it in a way that it had the same *z1* (mentioned above) and consequently the same signature of *y1*? (since signature depends only on message (*z*), private key and the random value *k*)

This transaction *y2* would be valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but that is hard. This is known as a collision, and you would be finding a collision in SHA256. Because you would be reusing a known hash, what you would be doing is performing a preimage attack. Since SHA256 has no known preimage attack for all 64 rounds done in a normal SHA256 hash, you would need to do 2^256 hashes in order to be guaranteed to have found a colliding preimage for that hash.

This is why a cryptographically secure hash is used for signing operations.